# Setting up different fade in time and fade out time in CSS

Tags: css

I want to build a header when you hover it after some milliseconds to be shown, but when to move out of it I want to stay for example 2-3 seconds then fade, somehow like setting up different fade in time and fade out time In CSS?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Have you investigated CSS animation?

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

**CSS**:

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
}
```

The background is white so that we can blend it in with the webpage, if your background color is different then change it.

**HTML**:

```
<div onmouseover="fade()" class=header></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function fade() {
    var styles = `
    .header {
        background: black;
        -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
        animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
        50% { opacity: 1; }
    }

    @keyframes fadeinout {
        50% { opacity: 1; }
    }
`

    var style = document.createElement("style")
    style.type = "text/css"
    style.innerText = styles
    document.head.appendChild(style)
}
```

Once hovered it will fade in for 4 seconds, then fade out for 4 seconds.